# Import to Local database from access

Tags: ms-access

I am developing a new system. the old one uses access database which is pretty horrible considering the large amount of data stored there and the amount of people using the program.
So I thought it might be better to use the Local database item (Add new item > Data > Local Database) that visual studio offers and place it on a shared folder (just the same way the access db is used with the old program [a server is not an option right now]).
**I was wondering if there is a way to import the data and tables from the access contains to the Local database I add to my project? (maybe through an exported file from the access like ODBC file)**

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are going to share a database with multiple users, using a server seems like the only sane way to go. Putting a "local database" (don't know what that is, perhaps MS SQL Embedded?) on a share and then letting your application access that sounds just... horrible. A properly-designed backend/frontend Access database will be far more stable. It might also help if you specify Visual Studio version and what kind of database this "local database" is, exactly...

Comment: It's sane relative to this specific system and I do that only because I don't have any server avilable. the access database is also on a share. visual studion 2010. Add new item to your project > Data > Local Database - I tought it might be more efficient than the access db.

Comment: I don't think so. SQL CE seems to be single user only. I'd suggest Tim Lentine's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, but I am fairly certain that a local database in VS as you have described it will be adding a [SQL CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172417.aspx) database which becomes embedded within your application and would not be comparable to an Access database on a file share somewhere on your network. You probably are looking at a minimum of using SQL Server Express for this type of design.
If you do use SQL Server Express, you can "upsize" the Access database to SQL Server easily enough using Microsoft Access.

Comment: umm yes it adds the db to the project, but I can move the db to the shared folder and just modify the connection to it's new location. I'm guessing SQL SE requires a server which I can't afford.

Comment: @gavra No that's the beauty of Express, you can install it on any standalone machine. Performance is better on a dedicated server but it's not essential that you use one.

Comment: I don't exactly understand. what you mean is I can install SQL SE on the computer that is meant to store the DB, then import (somehow) to a db (which db? how do I create it?) from access? thank you!

Comment: @gavra You install SQL Server Express on the machine that will host the data. You can then run the Access Upsizing Wizard to create a database on the SQL Express instance and migrate the existing data to SQL Server. See this link for more details: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-the-upsizing-wizard-HP005273009.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I'll explore you idea. it's a bit hard to have access to that machine that will store the db (in my case) so I might just use the Local database.

Comment: @gavra It might be worth looking into what happens to the local database when the application shuts down. I believe SQL CE is embedded within the application, so if the application isn't running on the host machine what happens when someone attempts to connect from another machine? I might not be following your app architecture properly, but SQL Express might be a better overall fit since the SQL Server is designed to run as a service on the machine.

Comment: @gavra: also test what happens if your application runs on two machines and both try to edit the "local database". See if you get any errors or data corruption... that might convince you to use a server after all. Another option could be to use the local dbs locally on each desktop and synchronize the data - which sounds like too much work to me.